# Receiving Null when attempting to retrieve checkbox values from Access table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

What I did was append the checkboxes as additional columns of a query which was then used to create a recordset. This recordset was then assigned to a combobox control.

Previously, it worked fine for me to then reference columns of the selected row in the combobox that were not displayed. However, no matter what I try, when I attempt to reference these checkboxes, all I get is a null value.

To illustrate:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT AG.Acttype, AG.ActGroupID, AT.HasLots, AT.IsLotSrce, " _
    & "AT.HasStructs FROM ActivityGroup AG, ActivityType AT WHERE (" _
    & FormatToSQLVal(Me![WizardSubformDisplay].Form![ActLinkedProjInput].Column(1)) _
    & " = AG.ProjectID) AND (AG.Acttype = AT.ActType);")

Set Me![WizardSubformDisplay].Form![ActTypeInput].Recordset = rs
```

(in this case there is the additional following tinkering which didn't cause trouble for other cases that didn't deal with checkboxes)

```
Me![WizardSubformDisplay].Form![ActTypeInput] = Me![ActTypeName]
Me![WizardSubformDisplay].Form![ActTypeInput].Locked = True
```

(I set the combobox to a specific choice and then lock it)

```
Me![WizardSubformDisplay].Form![ActTypeInput].Column(2),
Me![WizardSubformDisplay].Form![ActTypeInput].Column(3),
Me![WizardSubformDisplay].Form![ActTypeInput].Column(4)
```

all return null, rather than -1 if the box is checked and 0 otherwise.

Comment: I do not see why you are using a subform in a non-standard way. Why do you set a Recordset rather than a Record Source? Why don't you just bind the checkboxes to fields? Why have you got a circular reference?